# What does $fix-mqs do in Jake Archibald's IE Sass mixins?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass

I'm confused about the purpose of the `$fix-mqs` in http://jakearchibald.github.com/sass-ie/

I can see how the rest of the mixin works but can't figure this part out. I have used this pattern it in a project and everything seems to work if I ignore it and put a fixed width in an old-ie include on the body or generic wrapper element, for example:

```
.l-wrapper {
    @include old-ie {
        width: 960px;
    }
}
```

So my question is what is `$fix-mqs` for and what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that respond-min() mixin will act as a media query for you when you set `$fix-mqs` (fix media queries) to a specific width.  You'll end up with a document that only contains styles that are applicable to the defined width and no media queries.

For instance, if `$fix-mqs: 700px` (roughly desktop sized) and you called `respond-min(400px)`, then it wouldn't emit those styles because they're too small.  It *would* generate the styles when you invoke `respond-min(800px)`.

It's not just for IE, though.  Some very old mobile devices don't understand media queries either.  While most people recommend going "mobile first" with your media queries, there are some very destructive stylings (which are typically a pain to undo) that I'll apply only when it's a narrow device (such reformatting a wide table to appear vertically).

Comment: My understanding of the code is that `$fix-mqs` is false everywhere except all-old-ie.scss because of ``$fix-mqs: false !default;` therefore `@if $fix-mqs` is false.

Comment: So where's the confusion?  If it is false, then media queries are generated.  Otherwise it acts as a media query for you.

Answer (score 0):

`$fix-mqs` is only used by `respond-min` and `respond-max` in the IE stylesheet.

You set `$fix-mqs` to be the width your desktop styles kick in, but probably before your "massive" desktop styles kick in (if you have any).

Eg, if I set `$fix-mqs: 900px`, the IE stylesheet picks up all styles the normal stylesheet would if the viewport width were 900px.

In practice, when you call `respond-min(400px) { /* styles */ }` the normal stylesheet get a media query, whereas the IE stylesheet gets the styles if `400px` is less than or equal to `$fix-mqs`, otherwise it gets nothing.

Similarly, when you call `respond-max(400px) { /* styles */ }` the IE stylesheet gets the styles if `400px` is *greater* than `$fix-mqs`, otherwise it gets nothing.